# Font awesome icons within anchor tags not clickable. Is there a way to do it?

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I can't seem to make my font awesome icons clickable. Placing them inside anchor tags was the most popular response to others who have had this problem but its not working for me. If i click the background within the anchor tags and around the icon, it shows the dropdown menu i want, but if i click on the actual icon the dropdown won't open. As you can imagine this is a pain on mobile when most will be trying to click the icon. Help please!

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" href="#">  
    <i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i>  
    <h6 class="iconSub">News</h6>  
  </a>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn' || '.fa--pen-square'))  {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35185974/7393973) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: It's probably opening and closing; note the difference between the class name in the HTML (`fa-pen-square`) and in the JavaScript (`fa--pen-square`)...

Comment: Should probably use the generic `.fa` class (is `.fas` a typo?).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320998/font-awesome-icons-not-working-as-links) suggests adding target attributes on your anchors.

Comment: @isherwood `.fas` and `.far` are in new versions of Font Awesome. [example](https://fontawesome.com/icons/eye-slash?style=solid)

Comment: Good to know. I meant using the generic class as opposed to the specific icon class, which makes the script fragile. The icon could be changed at some point.

Comment: This code `matches('.dropbtn' || '.fa--pen-square')` is incorrect.  The result of that OR expression will always be `.dropbtn`.  Also, you have a double dash in there, whereas the element has only one dash.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. I tried wrapping the icon in a div or span and i corrected the error in the class name but it still doesn't work. Not sure if adding a target attribute can do what im looking for either. Very odd, still just everything around the icon will open the dropdown, but not the icon itself.

Answer (score 2):

Following format works fine for me:

```
<a href="#gotocontentdown">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

mine are clickable with the following format:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
  <span title="Edit">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: I think I should clarify. Linking to another page or linking to an external site works just fine. But i can't get it to to show the dropdown menu when its clicked, only clicking around the icon shows the dropdown menu.

Comment: Did you get any resolution for it? 

I am facing same issue, I am able to navigate to other page on icon click but my script to open popup doesn't work on icon click but it works when I click on empty space around the icon