# React FontAwesome Icon disappears when I add <a> tag

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, anchor, react-component

I am trying to add links to my font-awesome react component.

```
<div>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} size="2x" />
<div>
```

The component above renders the `faHome` icon.

But when I add anchor tag around it, it does not render. I can still see that the component in inspector tools with `<svg>` tag also loaded the same way when I didn't have anchor tag in the first example.

```
<div>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/jamesqquick">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} size="2x" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320998/font-awesome-icons-not-working-as-links

Answer (score 1):

it is working perfectly. Please check the below code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faHome } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} size="2x" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here is the Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-shockley-son3v)

[Here is output](https://son3v.csb.app/)